Locate specific column value from starting point in df then going backwards that matches some condition
i need to locate a value from a specific point in my dataframe backwards satisfying some condition. For example, the df below
index | ItemName | Price | Source | Cost
1   | toyHorse | 2.99  | Japan  | 2.25
2   | toyDog   | 2.50  | Cambodia | 1.80
3   | toyCat   | 2.75  | China | 1.10
4   | toyHorse | 5.00  | Japan | 3.75
so first, I need to find toyHorse where price >= 5.00. Then starting from that row, looking backwards, I need find the immediate prior match where it's toyHorse, Japan, and get the last cost of 2.25 and express it as a percentage of current sale price which is 2.25 / 5.00 in a new column called "PastPricePoint" so the desired output is below:
| ItemName | Price | PastPricePoint
| toyHorse | 5.00 | 0.45 ( calculated from 2.25/5.00)
it is important that as a filter for starting point of some price, the dataframe only looks at the immediate prior row that matches the criteria for this calculation.

The below code works for me
def conditional_cost(df,matching_val,price_threshold):
    df['lag']=df.groupby(['ItemName'])['Cost'].shift()
    df['PastPricePoint ']=np.where(((df["ItemName"]==matching_val) & (df['Price']>=price_threshold)),df['lag']/df['Price'],np.nan)
    
    return df

out_df=conditional_cost(input_df,"toyHorse",5)
print(out_df)

or in case if you want it to do for all values in ItemName (not just toy horse) then use the one below
def conditional_cost(df,price_threshold):
    df['lag']=df.groupby(['ItemName'])['Cost'].shift()
    df['PastPricePoint ']=np.where((df['Price']>=price_threshold),df['lag']/df['Price'],np.nan)
    
    return df

out_df=conditional_cost(input_df,5)
print(out_df)

shift is a function in pandas which can move up or down  values in a series (or column) by a specified number of rows. In your case, we are moving it down by 1 row. We are combining this function with groupby which means we are moving values down 1 row within same Item names.

Hi Pawan- Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, it works well! I'm fairly new to pandas, if you have an additional moment, would you mind explaining your thinking so I can learn from you, especially the "shift" method combined with df['lag']=df.groupby(['ItemName'])['Cost'].shift() as well as the np.where. I really appreciate it!

if it helped, consider accepting the answer. I have made edits to my answer to explain the solution
